# 秘書選び問題での見送る数の決め方

Tags: アルゴリズム

最適停止問題に秘書選び問題というものがありますが、見送る数はどのように決めるべきなのでしょう。
[Wikipediaの説明](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%98%E6%9B%B8%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C)は、私には難しいです。

---

追記
回答いただいた方法で最適な値を得ることが出来ました
しかし、時々良い値でない場合もあったためもう一度調べ直したところ
同様の問題で期待値を最大化する方法があるそうです。
数式を見たのですが、結局のところ具体的な計算の方法が理解できず検算が出来ません
少ない数で構わないので具体的な計算方法を教えて下さい。

---

計算方法がわからなかった式

> i番目に面接したものの相対順位が[image: r_i]以上であればこれを採用しそうでなければ見送る。
>
> [image: 計算方法がわからなかった式]
>   アルゴリズム辞典 共立出版 (1994/08)P.646

Comment: 最適ポリシーの導出が難しいということですか？それとも動的計画法が難しいということでしょうか。

Comment: 最適ポリシーという言葉の意味がよくわからないのですが、最適ポリシーの導出が難しいだと思います。動的計画法と秘書選び問題は別の問題だと認識しているので

Comment: 数式を載せたいのですが、なにか参考になる情報はありませんか

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76902 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164286 あたりが参考になるかと思います．

Comment: Wikipediaの解説が難しいということでしたが、追加質問 (基本報酬問題のことですね) での期待値ならWikipediaの解説に載ってる式の方が単純ですので、Wikipediaの式を使ってみてはいかが？

Comment: Wikipedia の、基本報酬問題の解説を読み直したら、「 **応募者** 」と「 **候補者** 」が取り違えられてる部分があるような。あの解説の c は、c番目以降の「候補者」 **ではなく** 「 **応募者** 」を採用するという意味であるべきのはず。

Answer (score 7):

応募者の数が n 人で十分大きな数の場合

- 見送る人数を (n / e) にすると最善の秘書を雇える確率が最大となる。
- その確率は 1 / e である。

というのが、秘書選び問題（秘書問題）の解です。

ここで使われている e は、ネイピア数、オイラー数、自然対数の底などと呼ばれていて、その値は 2.718281828459045...（以下略）です。
e は、円周率と同様、無理数なので、小数点以下の数は無限に続きます。

何故このような結果になるのかは Wikipedia などで解説されていますが、確率の知識と、微積分の知識がないと理解するのが難しいと思います。でも、何人見送れば良いかは、簡単に電卓で計算できます。

例えば、応募者が 100 人だとすると、見送る数は、100 / 2.71824 = 36.7885... ですから、 37 人(割り切れないので、四捨五入してください）。
そして、残った人の中から見送った 37 人の誰よりも優れた人を選べば良い訳です。

「だいたい、応募者の３分の１を見送って、見送った中で最良だった人を超える人が表れたら、その人を選ぶ」ぐらいで実用になります。